# ParseError: syntax error, unexpected token "<"

Tags: php, magento, syntax

I'm getting this error when I try to acces Magento Admin Configuration:

**An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details.**

my system.log says:
main.CRITICAL: ParseError: syntax error, unexpected token "<", expecting end of file in /home/seedsat/public_html/magento244/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/app/code/MGS/ThemeSettings/view/adminhtml/templates/system/config/head.phtml:1

The header.phtml starts like this:

```
<?php $helper = $this->helper('MGS\ThemeSettings\Helper\Config') ?>
<?php $fonts = $helper->getFonts(); ?>
<?php $customFont = $helper->getCustomFonts(); ?>
<?php //echo '<pre>'; print_r($customFont); die(); ?>
```

Where is the problem here?

Comment: First line lacks a semicolon.

Comment: Theres no need for all the PHP tags. The first opening one is enough. All others including the closing ones can be removed.